# Broken Score on Game Sketch

Tags: programming, c++, sketch

I have modified the code for Flappy Duino to give me a score at the end of the game. Here is the code:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_PCD8544.h>

Adafruit_PCD8544 display = Adafruit_PCD8544(7, 6, 5, 4, 3);

#include "Sprite.h"
#include "Chym.h"
#include "Bar.h"

Chym player;
Bar bar; Bar bar2;
int gameScore = 0;
int highScore = 0;
int KNOCK_PIN = 2;
int LED_PIN = 8;

boolean clicked = false;

void loop(){}

void resetGame() {
  player.respawn();
  bar.setPos(0, 20);
  bar2.setPos(50, 30);
  gameScore = 0;
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  display.begin();
  display.setContrast(50);
  display.clearDisplay();
  display.display();

  digitalWrite(LED_PIN, HIGH);

  pinMode(KNOCK_PIN, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(LED_PIN, OUTPUT);

  resetGame();

  while(1) {
    getInput();
    player.update();
    bar.update(); bar2.update();
    drawLCD();
  }
}

void getInput() {
  int knock = digitalRead(KNOCK_PIN);
  if (knock == 0) { // push down
    clicked = true;
    gameScore = gameScore + 1;
    Serial.println(gameScore);
  } 
  else {
    clicked = false;
  }
}

void drawLCD() {
  display.clearDisplay();

  if (!player.isDead()) {
    int ht1 = bar.hitTest(player.getX(), player.getY());
    int ht2 = bar2.hitTest(player.getX(), player.getY());
    int die = ht1 + ht2;
    if (die == 1) {
        // game over
        player.die();
    }

    if (clicked) {
      player.flyUp();
    } 
    else {
      player.cancelJump();
    }
    player.render();    

    bar.render(); bar2.render(); 
  } 
  else {
    if (gameScore >> highScore) {
      highScore = gameScore;
    }
    display.setCursor(0, 0);
    display.setTextSize(1);
    display.print("ur Score- ");
    display.println(gameScore);
    display.print("HI Score- ");
    display.println(highScore);
    if (clicked) {
      resetGame();
    }
  }

  display.display();
}
```

The first time the game runs thru the gameScore is greater than highScore so gameScore and highScore print as the same. However every other time the function is called up the highScore doesn't change even when the following statement is true:

```
if (gameScore >> highScore) {
          highScore = gameScore;
        }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
if (gameScore >> highScore)
```

You have the wrong operator there.  `>>` is *right shift*, so you are right shifting the `gameScore` by `highScore` bits, which if it's more than 16 will end up as 0.

Instead you just want `>` for *greater than*:

```
if (gameScore > highScore)
```

Comment: Does the same apply to operators such as ||, &&, ==? Could I have used >=?

Comment: Full list of operators: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_operators.htm